# Evaluating a double sigma

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, factorial

Evaluate $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{m!n!}{(m+n+2)!}$$ How do I start with the problem? Infinite sum of factorials?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1597845/168053) for a very neat solution by @OlivierOloa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Evaluating a **double** sigma. How do I **start** with the problem ?*

By evaluating a ***simple*** sigma! ;-$)$ Could you prove that the inner sum evaluates to $\dfrac1{(m+1)^2}$ ?

My bet is that it [telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), due to some clever algebraic manipulations of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Afterwards, see [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: Alternately, you can use the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).